# How to subscript with 2 words with a space in between, for example: $m_{negative gradient$?

Tags: subscripts

How to subscript with 2 words, for example: $m_{negative gradient$?

[image]

I want to have 
m_postive gradient

my code:

```
 m_{negative gradient}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{amsmath}` and then `m_{\text{negative gradient}}`.  Note that the standard in math typesetting is that words in math will be upright, and only variables will be italic.  Thus, "negative gradient" will be upright.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes `\text` is a wee bit dangerous, since it will inherit the font of the surrounding text (e.g. in a theorem).

Answer (score 1):

note that even for one word you want `\mathrm{positive}`, a sequence of letters in math italic is designed to look like a product of variables not a word, `_{\mathrm{positive\ gradient}}` would work  (or you could use `_{\textrm{positive gradient}}` but mathrm is perhaps preferable here.

Comment: Uhm, the control space makes a _really_ large space. I find `\mathrm{positive\;gradient}` more appealing.

Comment: Why not use `\text`?

Comment: @manooooh because `\text` picks up teh current text font from outside the math,  so if you have italic theorems it would be italic for example. `\textrm` is better as it is a fixed fornt but it takes the roman font from the test setup which may not be the same as the roman font set up for math.

Comment: @campa grr yes in a subscript I may edit later to get the space from the font at that size if it isn't too much code, or as you say a math space is probably OK